# Will drywall mud adhere to semi-gloss paint?

Tags: drywall-mud

We want to texture several walls that have semi-gloss paint on them.  Will drywall mud adhere to the paint or do we need to use a particular primer first?

Comment: I would do a small test.  Clean with TSP, apply a dab of mud, let dry and then try to chip it off.

Comment: No nononono. You will need to sand the sheen down, *then* use a bonding primer, then texture.

Answer (score 1):

I have roughed up the surface with red scotch brite pad or by sanding (scotch brite doesn’t make as big a mess).

Then wipe with a damp rag to remove the loose particles after that the mud will stick I have done this hundreds if not thousands of times on my own home and remodels, rewires where I had to patch holes used to drill and pull wire. + Jimmie fix it method may be a better way but takes time and I have not had failures.